# iOS Error: Running the project on iOS12 gives an error, but it works fine on iOS11

Tags: ios

The project enters the background, switches the wifi network, and enters the project to make a network request. The request process will report an error. The error message is as follows:

> xxx(739,0x16ca7f000) malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is
>   damaged at 0x280c78fa0
>
> *** Incorrect guard value: 206401777864449
>
> xxx(739,0x16ca7f000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in
>   malloc_error_break to debug.

[image]

Comment: "malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug" So did you do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045208/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-malloc-error-break-to-debug

Comment: Have you tried running with Address Sanitizer enabled? Here is a question about turning it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150924/

Comment: I have tried set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug, but I have not got anything.

Answer (score 10):

```
xcode10 -- Edit scheme -- Diagnostics -- select "Address Sanitizer"
```